# Get Facebook Page Photostream using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get a Facebook page photo stream using the Graph API? For example the photo stream of coca cola page is at: https://www.facebook.com/cocacola/photos_stream.

Answer (score -1):

Possible Connections: (?metadata=1)

```
   "metadata": {
      "connections": {
         "picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/picture",
         "feed": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed",
         "posts": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts",
         "tagged": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/tagged",
         "statuses": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/statuses",
         "links": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/links",
         "notes": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/notes",
         "photos": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/photos",
         "albums": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/albums",
         "events": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/events",
         "videos": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/videos",
         "questions": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/questions",
         "offers": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/offers",
         "milestones": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/milestones",
         "global_brand_children": "https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/global_brand_children"
      },
```

If you want to find photos in their stream, why not use /posts and loop through to find posts with pictures?

Comment: that's not what he asked... there is photos connections and albums too, can they be retrieved, if so, and it's not his personal page, how to get an access token for that page ?